# I keep receiving ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'specreduce' when I try to import specreduce

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, astropy

I was following a tutorial, and I originally tried typing 
from specreduce.calibration_data import load_MAST_calspec, which gave the same error.
I'm not sure how to properly import specreduce, so if anyone could show me how to do that I would be very appreciative!

Comment: Did you install the `specreduce` package?

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to do that. Is it not installed when astropy is installed?

Comment: No, installing astropy only installs the core `astropy` package.  specreduce is apparently an [affiliated package](https://github.com/astropy/specreduce); a separate special-purpose package built on Astropy.   It seems they have not published a release on PyPI so you should contact its authors to ask how best to install it.  It seems for now you might be able to install directly from the repository with `pip install git+https://github.com/astropy/specreduce.git`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked!

Comment: Cool, I'm glad. I'll re-post my comment as an answer then

Answer (score 0):

Installing `astropy` only installs the core astropy package. specreduce is apparently an [affiliated package](https://github.com/astropy/specreduce)--a separate special-purpose package built on Astropy. It seems they have not published a release on PyPI so you should contact its authors to ask how best to install it. It seems for now you might be able to install directly from the repository with `pip install git+https://github.com/astropy/specreduce.git`.